# Package Keyval Error: allcolors undefined

Tags: packages, package-writing

I am using the following template for writing a document in Latex  but i am getting an error `Package Keyval Error: allcolors undefined.`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,headings=normal]{scrartcl}

% Load some packages 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}  % Use this if you are writing in English.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Use this if you are writing in German.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}

% Some settings
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex}
% \titlespacing{ command }{ left }{ before-sep }{ after-sep }[ right-sep ]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2ex}{0ex}

% Pdf annotation (Metadata for pdf document)
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Title for pdf Metadata}}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Forename Surename}}

\begin{document}
University XYZ\hfill \today\\ % Date can also be set by hand (replace \today)
Faculty of Electrical Engg

\begin{center}
\sffamily\bfseries\large
%
% = Title ====================================
Template of Writing a Document in latex
% ============================================
%
\vspace{0.4cm}
\rmfamily\mdseries\normalsize
--- Arbeitsplan zur Masterarbeit --- % Or Master's/Bachelor's Thesis Work Plan
\end{center}
%
% = Student ==================================
Bearbeiter: ABC\\ % Student
Course: Undergrad Program
% ============================================

% Load content from the file content.tex
\input{content}

% References as defined in the BibTeX file references.bib
\small
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliographystyle{get_eng_alphadin}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem here when I comment out `\input{content}` and `\bibliography{references}` (since we don't have those).

Comment: @Werner: May be i am getting the error because i do not have the required package installed in my machine. The template is actually a working template but its giving me error in my machine. I am new to Latex so, i don't know how can i resolve the matter (i have already searched over internet.)

Comment: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: @Werner: Sorry, as i mentioned that i am new to this thing so, only thing i could understand is that i should update my package manager and packages but when i am trying to run `tlmgr update --list` through the terminal (root user) then, it says that the command not found.

Comment: Are you running TeX Live? What OS are you using?

Comment: i am using TexLive with TexMaker Editor in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: TexMaker is an editor. Ubuntu is an Operating System (OS); I run on Windows, sorry. I want to know what your TeX *distribution* is. You're most likely running TeX Live, so try `sudo tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, i have already mentioned that i am using TexLive alongwith TexMaker Editor. I have already tried to run the command mentioned by you but it says `No command 'tlmgr'`

Comment: @skm then you are using the Ubuntu TeX Live, and it cannot be updated.

Comment: @skm Ubuntu uses an older version of the TeX programs and packages, which it confusingly bundles under the name `texlive`. At the same time, the TeX Users Group online (www.tug.org) offers the up-to-date versions separately, called TeXLive2014. `tlmgr` is the installer program that comes with TeXLive2014 and allows you to update LateX packages. The Ubuntu version does not include this program, as you are supposed to just use `apt`/`aptitude`. Heiko has pointed you toward the best solution for having a current TeX system on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Option `allcolors` was added to `hyperref` in version 2011-02-05 v6.82a. Therefore you need to update `hyperref`.

TeX distributions from Linux distributions are often very old and programs like `tlmgr` are disabled to avoid interference with the Linux packaging system.

But a recent TeXLive can be installed in parallel, e.g. see

[How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/16967)

[Enrico Gregorio: Installing TeX Live 2010 on Ubuntu](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100gregorio.pdf)

Comment: thanks for your answer. The same kind of suggestion is given in the above comments but the problem is that i am not able to update it through terminal. Terminal says `No command 'tlmgr'`.